# How to include elastic/search-ui in an Angular project?

Tags: angular, elasticsearch, elastic-search-ui

I am trying to build a search page using [@elastic-search-ui](https://www.elastic.co/enterprise-search/search-ui?size=n_6_n) and following the [headless concepts](https://github.com/elastic/search-ui/blob/master/ADVANCED.md#headless-core-concepts) way of adding it, shows errors.

1. Built a new angular application
2. in `package.json` (adding them under `devDependencies` or `dependencies` has the same issue).

```
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    ..    
    "@elastic/search-ui": "^1.9.0",
    "@elastic/search-ui-site-search-connector": "1.9.0",
```

3. In `app.module.ts`

```
...
import { SearchDriver } from '@elastic/search-ui';
...
```

throws a compilation error as:

```
Error: src/app/app.module.ts:7:30 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file 
for module '@elastic/search-ui'. /Users/s/angular-elastic-search-ui/node_modules/@elastic/search-ui/lib/index.js' 
implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm i --save-dev @types/elastic__search-ui` if it exists or 
add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module '@elastic/search-ui';`
```

Comment: Did you manage to get this working? I’m in a similar situation now

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still need help, but I suggest trying Elastic App Search Javascript client, https://github.com/elastic/app-search-javascript. I'm currently using it in a React SPA++.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).